# External Jquery code causing errors in react

Tags: reactjs

```
Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.
WARNING in [eslint]
src\js\main.js
  Line 8:3:     'use strict' is unnecessary inside of modules  strict
  Line 22:46:   Expected '===' and instead saw '=='            eqeqeq
  Line 22:103:  Expected '===' and instead saw '=='            eqeqeq
  Line 28:34:   Expected '===' and instead saw '=='            eqeqeq

ERROR in [eslint]
src\js\main.js
  Line 7:1:    Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions    
  Line 22:9:   Unexpected use of 'location'                                           no-restricted-globals    
  Line 22:85:  Unexpected use of 'location'                                           no-restricted-globals    
  Line 194:5:  'AOS' is not defined                                                   no-undef
  Line 203:4:  'jQuery' is not defined                                                no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

web pack compiled with 1 error and 1 warning
```

I imported external JavaScript file in react index.js and that External jQuery code causing errors in react.

Comment: These are all linting errors. Fix eslint errors

Answer (score 0):

These are linting errors and you just need to correct the issues that are listed. For example: you should remove the words “use strict” from your code on line 8.